# Apollo Cold Welding Mitigation

Tags: materials, apollo-11, manufacturing, structural-design, cold-welding

I am currently debating with someone on a different platform and he brought up the phenomenon "cold welding." I must admit that I had never heard of that before, so I have been reading about it for a while now. I have been trying to find any documentation that NASA employed some kind of mitigation techniques to avoid moving parts being fused together. From what I imagine, the lander had only a few moving parts, but I am curious if anyone knows if they did anything to prevent cold welding. I am also curious about the cameras. The shutter on the 70MM camera is a moving part, and most likely made of aluminum, but I can't find any information about it. It seems as if aluminum is rather prone to cold welding. I am guessing they used a lubricant on the moving parts of the camera, but I don't know if there is a place to find that information.

Any help would be awesome. This denier I am writing back and forth with is bringing up topics I have never looked into before, so I am happy to learn new things as I am doing my research.

Comment: Arguing with them is fruitless. Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/how-do-we-know-the-apollo-moon-landings-are-real

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: [How is the unwanted cold welding prevented in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4169)

Comment: somewhat related with helpful links: [What is the air pressure threshold for cold welding?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17217/12102) and [Bronze material compatibility for mechanism exposed to LEO](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50156/12102)

Comment: Just leave the [conspiracy theorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_theory) alone, their goal is the continuation of "discussions" forever by any means necessary rather than a pursuit of facts or logic. It's an endless, fruitless [game of cat and mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_and_mouse).

Comment: @uhoh Yep. My prediction: The OP will find evidence that cold wielding was not a huge issue, present it to the person with whom the OP is arguing, and the wing nut with whom the OP is arguing will drop that claim only to come up with another bogus claim. There is no way of winning an argument against those who are immune to logic and evidence. You called it cat and mouse. Another name is whack-a-mole.

Comment: @DavidHammen yes indeed, whack-a-mole *nails it.*